# Questions regarding the algorithm question in LeetCode - Remove Duplicates from Sorted Array using Java

Tags: java, algorithm

I am working on an algorithm problem on Leetcode. But first I wrote my answer on my own local compiler. When running my code locally, I can get the answer to this question. But when I paste my answer directly into the online compiler on leetcode, the system prompts me that my answer is wrong. Cannot match the correct answer.
**The solution from my local compiler shown below:**

```
class Solution {
    public int removeDuplicates(int[] nums) {
        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<Integer> arraylist = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        for (int i : nums) {
            list.add(i);
        }

        for (int num : list) {
            if (!arraylist.contains(num)) {
                arraylist.add(num);
            }
        }

        return arraylist.size();
    }
}
```

And the feedback from LeetCode:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XLWHQ.png)

Comment: Unclear what you mean, the screenshot says your code returns the wrong value and not that it has compilation errors. Also it looks like you have misunderstood the requirements.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I am confused, why the assignment says, that the `nums` array is `passed by reference`. Isn't Java always `pass-by-value`?

Comment: Also, instead of two `ArrayLists`, you could just use `Set`, as it can't contain duplicate elements.

Comment: I believe the question wants you to alter the original array.

Comment: @Sujit No "belief" necessary, it's a fact since the challenge explicitly says so: *"remove the duplicates **in-place**"*.

Answer (score 2):

Some comments say that a set could be used, but the task is to do so without any additional memory allocation, the simplest solution is:

```
private static int removeDuplicates(int[] numbers) {
    int size = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        if (i == 0 || numbers[i - 1] != numbers[i]) {
            numbers[size++] = numbers[i];
        }
    }
    return size;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

set index to 1, if nums[i] is different from nums[i + 1] then increment index by 1

```
class Solution {
    public int removeDuplicates(int[] nums) {
        
        int index = 1;
        
        for(int i = 0; i < nums.length - 1; i++){
            if(nums[i] != nums[i + 1]){
                nums[index++] = nums[i + 1];
            }
        }
        return index;
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `List`, `Set`, `Map`, or anything like that. The data is **sorted**. Use that!

Actually, ask yourself how your output is `[1, 1]`, when you can only return a single `int` value. How can you output a list/array with only a single number?

So read the challenge description again, first sentence:

> ... remove the duplicates **in-place** ... return the new length.

Since this is your challenge, I'm not going to write the code.